# Como usar th:if

Tags: spring-mvc

Bom dia, alguem saberia me dizer a forma correta de usar o "th:if" do Thymeleaf com Spring MVC, estou tentando dessa forma mas não estou conseguindo ..

```
th:if="${situacao_financeira} eq 'A'"
```

Comment: rapaz....eu acho que é isso: `th:if="${situacao_financeira == 'A'}"`

Comment: Consgue resolver .. criei um método na classe testando se a situação .. se fosse paga devolvo true senão false .. com isso consegui controlar ..

Answer (score 1):

Ficou da seguinte forma:

No model:

```
public boolean aPagar() {
        if(situacao_financeira.equals("A"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

e na View

```
<div class="form-group" th:if="${inscricao.aPagar()}">
```